# Different conditions, same result. Why?

Tags: javascript

Creating a sort function for a very simple todo app in a Javascript tutorial. My answer and the tutorials answer are different but yield the same results. I know different code can achieve the same results but I'm just wondering why? I'm not sure how to test my code to see where it could fail. Code below.

CODE:

```
const todoList = [{
    title: 'Work on JS course',
    completed: true
}, {
    title: 'School activity with Eleanor',
    completed: false
}, {
    title: 'Coach Susan',
    completed: true
}, {
    title: 'Go over Step study homework',
    completed: false
}, {
    title: 'Message car buyer',
    completed: true
}]

//my answer
const sortTodo = function (todoList) {
    todoList.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.completed < b.completed) {
            return -1
        } else if (b.completed < a.completed) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    })
}

//video answer
const sortTodo = function (todoList) {
    todoList.sort( function (a, b) {
        if (!a.completed && b.completed) {
            return -1
        } else if (!b.completed && a.completed) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    })
}
```

answer: (my answer and the video answer both get this result)

```
$ node todo.js
[ { title: 'School activity with Eleanor', completed: false },
  { title: 'Go over Step study homework', completed: false },
  { title: 'Work on JS course', completed: true },
  { title: 'Coach Susan', completed: true },
  { title: 'Message car buyer', completed: true } ]
```

Comment: JavaScript defines the boolean values `false` and `true` to be ordered such that `false` is less than `true`.

Comment: if you wrote the first code then it seems that you should understand why both work. Using `<` and `>` when it comes to booleans doesn't feel natural though

Comment: To elaborate on @Pointy's answer, this is because `false = 0` and `true = 1` in binary.

Comment: @Adassko It feels more natural to me than the conjunctive normal form when using it in the context of a comparison function.